# QNetworkReply::ProtocolInvalidOperationError while uploading video to youtube

Tags: c++, qt, youtube-data-api, google-oauth, qnetworkrequest

After the authorization, I have called **uploadVideo** function. However I have taken **QNetworkReply::ProtocolInvalidOperationError**. `this->mOauth` is an instance of `QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow`. Where do I do wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
QNetworkReply * Uploader::uploadVideo(){
QNetworkRequest * request = new QNetworkRequest{videoInsertUrl};
request->setRawHeader("Authorization",
                      QStringLiteral("Bearer %1").arg(mOauth->token()).toLatin1() );


auto multiPart = new QHttpMultiPart{ QHttpMultiPart::MixedType };
auto videoPart = new QHttpPart{};

auto video = new QFile{ mFileName };
if (!video->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)){
    qDebug()<<" cannot to open video file";
    return nullptr;
}

videoPart->setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, QVariant("video/*"));
videoPart->setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("Slug"));

videoPart->setBodyDevice(video);
multiPart->append(*videoPart);

return this->mOauth->networkAccessManager()->post(*request,multiPart);
}
```

Comment: I get **Malformed multipart body** response from `reply->readAll()` .

Comment: Hard to answer without a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).